# WPF Dockpanel Button Scaling

Tags: c#, wpf

In my XAMl-Example only the the "Test2" Button is scaling properly to the window size. "Test1" is not affected by a resizing control. Why did I got that result and how can I make "Test1" properly scale with the window size? I got this XAML-Code:

```
<Window x:Class="testg.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testg"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Background="Gainsboro">
        <Button Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Test1</Button>
        <Button Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Test2</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are negating styles in buttons. If you want the width to be auto (smallest possible) then don't add HorizontalAlignment=Stretch (biggest possible). The weird behaviour is probably because DockPanel has a property LastChildFill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout doesn't make much sense. It's unclear why you have added a `DockPanel`.

Get rid of the `DockPanel` and put each `Button` that you want to scale in a cell of the `Grid` that stretches:

```
<Grid Background="Gainsboro">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button>Test1</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2">Test2</Button>
</Grid>
```

By the way, it's pointless to set the `Width` and `Height` properties of a `Button` to `Auto` and setting the `HorizontalAlignment` to Strectch. These are the default values.